# Update values depends on Condition in sql Procedure

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a table that contains four columns. I need to avoid inserting duplicate Service Name
for Particular ServerId. But i don't want to check description. Two or three services in particular ServerId having same description name.

**Table:-**

```
Id int,
ServerId int,
ServiceName varchar(200),
Description varchar(400)
```

**Procedure:-**

```
CREATE procedure sp_UpdateServices  
(  
@id int
,@ServerId int  
,@ServiceName varchar(500)  
,@Description varchar(400)
,@ReturnMessage nvarchar(500)= null output   
)  
as  
BEGIN  

 BEGIN TRY
 If Exists(SELECT servicename from tbl_servicename where 
 servicename=@ServiceName  AND    
 serverid=@ServerId )     
 RAISERROR('Service Name Already Exists',16,1)    

 BEGIN transaction
 Update tbl_servicename SET servicename=@ServiceName , description=@Description   
 where serverid=@ServerId and id=@id  
 COMMIT Transaction


 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
 if(@@trancount>0)
 rollback tran
 SELECT @ReturnMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE()     
 select @ReturnMessage as ReturnMessage 
 END CATCH 

 End
```

**Output:-**

```
id  serverid servicename description
379   218     test1        test1
385   218     test2        test1
```

**Issue:-**

I got Error if i try to save description test1 for both service name test1 and test1 .

Comment: `Description varchar(400)` v.s. `,@Description varchar(500)` ?

Comment: You are only updating the table,Do you want to insert new values?

Comment: What is your error? Also mention the parameters passed while executing the stored procedure

Comment: i am just Updating the records @Prasanth

Comment: Instead of doing this type of referential integrity in a stored procedure why not just create a unique constraint on those two columns? Something like this. create unique nonclustered index IX_U_tbl_servicename on tbl_servicename (servicename, serverid) I would suggest not adding the tbl_ prefix to your table names. They do nothing but make it more difficult to work with.

Comment: okay @Sean thanks for suggestion but is there any other way to overcome.

Comment: What do you mean by any other way? The correct way to ensure referential integrity here is with a unique index. Doing it in a procedure is not a good approach because if data is inserted another way your data is hosed.